# What does negative holdings in ETF mean?

Tags: etf

For example in [this ETF](https://www.td.com/ca/en/asset-management/funds/solutions/etfs/FundCard/TD%20International%20Equity%20CAD%20Hedged%20Index%20ETF/?fundId=6905), the full list of holdings as of today is:

TD International Equity Index ETF (TPE) 99.88%
Cash and Cash Equivalents   88.88%
JPY Currency    23.53%
CHF Currency    3.37%
SGD Currency    1.14%
HKD Currency    0.06%
USD Currency    0.02%
NOK Currency    -0.01%
AUD Currency    -0.03%
Singapore Dollar    -1.13%
Danish Krone    -1.6%
Swedish Krona   -2.38%
Swiss Franc -3.34%
Pound Sterling  -4.43%
Japanese Yen    -23.37%
Canadian Dollar -80.59%

What do these negative numbers mean?

Comment: It should be short position. My guess is it's created to hedge currency risk of holding international equity.